# How to partially revert/amend a pushed commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

There is a pushed commit that modifies e.g. 8 files.
I would like to revert that commit but only keep the changes in 2 of the files.
That is because I would like to change the implementation of this commit.
What I was thinking is to do a `git revert` and then on the revert commit `commit —amend` code so as to not have 1 revert and 1 new commit.
Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Now `master` branch is pointed to the previous commit and all your changes from the latest commit are in index. You leave in index changes you need and commit

Comment: It is not the latest commit though

Answer (score 0):

`git revert --no-commit`, then reset/checkout those files you do not want to revert.

`git commit --amend` and `git reset HEAD^`, followed by new commits, will conflict with `git push`.